# GCC C vector extension: How to test the result of a comparison (for conditional assignment, etc)?

Tags: c, gcc, vectorization, conditional-statements, ternary-operator

Background: GCC C's builtin vector extensions allow for a fairly natural representation of SIMD vectors as C "types." According to the documentation, many built-in operations are supported (+, -, etc). However, the ternary operator, as well as logical operators (&&, ||) for some reason only work in C++. This is an issue for an all=C codebase.

The question: In GCC C, how would one implement SIMD-compatible [branchless] conditionals of the form:

```
    v4si a = {2,-1,3,4}, b, indicesLessThan0;
    indicesLessThan0 = a < 0;
    b = indicesLessThan0 ? a : 0;
```

And, more generally, how to perform an arbitrary independent block of statements based on that same result:

```
v4si c = {9,8,7,6}, d;
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  if (indicesLessThan0[i]) { // consider tests one by one
     b[i] = a[i] // as the ternary operator does above
     d[i] = c[i] + 1; // some other independent operation
  }
  else {
     b[i] = 0; // as the ternary operator does above
     d[i] = c[i] - 1; // another independent operation
  } 
}
```

If doing a block of statements is harder (SIMD branching is bad), it would be fine to perform the ternary test again for any additional statements at the cost (supposedly) of some efficiency:

```
d = indicesLessThan0 ? c + 1 : c - 1; // the other operation in the loop
```

But the ternary operator doesn't work in C for some reason the manual doesn't explain. Is there another easy way? Some way of using if statements?

Comment: Can you explain why you insist on using gcc rather than g++, given that you want support of an extension that is supported by g++ and not gcc?   Either way, you will be using a compiler extension.

Comment: @Peter g++ is just gcc with different default options.

Comment: @Peter: actually, the vector extension of the **G**NU **C**ompiler **C**ollection is listed as a [C extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.2.0/gcc/Vector-Extensions.html#Vector-Extensions). The C++ extensions just state that most of the **C extensions** can also be used. (Note that the docs for pre-5 versions state the same)

Comment: Yes, I'm aware g++ is essentially gcc with different options.   But those options include C++ features.   If you have extensions that are C++-only (presumably because their implementation uses C++ language features that are not in C) then that means they are enabled in g++.

Comment: @Peter: If you mean the ternary operator being overloaded to test per vector-component, you should state that clearly or even make that an answer, I thinkt you are right. I would myself, but I cannot verify that right now. But that is still not related to the vector extensions per se.

Answer (score 4):

I have found 3 solutions as a result of hitting the code with the kitchen sink.

1. Switch to g++. Not too hard, and turns out most of the code can be swapped just by putting a (type *) before all the -allocs. Then I can just do:

   `v16s8 condStor = test ? a : b;`
2. Even better, I discovered you can just bitbash using various mixes of &'s and |'s, the same way everyone does with bits inside of integers. The trick is that vectors set all truth to 11111111... (-1 unsigned), which makes values stick when using bitwise operators.
3. Even better still, "type punning 101" with an intrinsic function:
   `v16s8 condStor = b; __builtin_ia32_maskmovdqu (a, test, (char *)(&condStor));`
   This takes advantage of the function dedicated to doing what #2 does in one fell swoop.

Not convinced? Check the assembly:

1. ```
   pxor    %xmm1, %xmm1
   movdqa  -64(%rbp), %xmm0
   pcmpeqb %xmm1, %xmm0
   pcmpeqd %xmm1, %xmm1
   pandn   %xmm1, %xmm0
   pxor    %xmm1, %xmm1
   pcmpgtb %xmm0, %xmm1
   movdqa  %xmm1, %xmm0
   movdqa  -32(%rbp), %xmm2
   movdqa  -16(%rbp), %xmm1
   pand    %xmm0, %xmm1
   pandn   %xmm2, %xmm0
   por %xmm1, %xmm0
   movaps  %xmm0, -80(%rbp)
   ```
2. ```
   movdqa  -64(%rbp), %xmm0
   movdqa  %xmm0, %xmm1
   pand    -16(%rbp), %xmm1
   pcmpeqd %xmm0, %xmm0
   pxor    -64(%rbp), %xmm0
   pand    -32(%rbp), %xmm0
   por %xmm1, %xmm0
   movaps  %xmm0, -80(%rbp)
   ```
3. ```
   movdqa  -32(%rbp), %xmm0
   movaps  %xmm0, -80(%rbp)
   leaq    -80(%rbp), %rax
   movdqa  -16(%rbp), %xmm0
   movdqa  -64(%rbp), %xmm1
   movq    %rax, %rdi
   maskmovdqu  %xmm1, %xmm0
   ```

   Judging by how convoluted 1 appears to be, followed by 2, followed by 3, I now see the cost of the C++ abstraction. Maybe this is what Linus was ranting about back in the day. (No, probably not.) Anyway, hope this helps someone!